# Solve system equation

Tags: equations

I want to write the step by step solution of a system equation in LaTeX. But, dispite I can write the system equation, I don't know how to write at the right side of this system equation the steps of the solution. This is the code I used to write the system:

```
$\left.
\begin{array}{rcl}
     \tan(\alpha) & = & \dfrac{h}{x}  \\ 
     \tan(\beta) & = & \dfrac{h}{d - x} 
\end{array}
\right\}$
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \begin{aligned}
    \tan(\alpha) &= \frac{h}{x}  \\
    \tan(\beta)  &= \frac{h}{d - x}
  \end{aligned}
  \right\}
  \text{First step}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Package `amsmath` provides `aligned` for equations systems inside an equation line. Then also `\dfrac` is not needed and `\frac` suffices.

There is also environment `rcases` of package `mathtools`, but it is not used here, because of the additional alignment.